# How to pass data from an object to its containing activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a utility class used to fetch a token with a Retrofit call. I am attempting to listen for callback's on this class's methods in its containing activity.

In class:

```
class TokenUtils() {

interface IGetTokenListener {

    fun onTokenRetreived(response: Boolean)
}

internal var callback: IGetTokenListener? = null


fun registerIGetTokenListener(callback: IGetTokenListener) {
    this.callback = callback
}

 private fun getToken() {



    val requestCall: Call<Token> = apiClass.getToken()


    requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Token> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Token>, t: Throwable) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Token>, response: Response<Token>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                callback?.onTokenRetrieved(true)

            } 

        }

    })
}
```

I am attempting to listen for the callback with an instance of this class in an activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 var tokenUtils = TokenUtils()


 private fun getToken(requestBody) {

        tokenUtils.registerIGetTokenListener(object:TokenUtils.IGetTokenListener{
            override fun onTokenRetrieved(response: Boolean) {

                if (response){
                    AppLog.i(TAG, "onTokenRetrieved() - Token retrieved successfully")


                } else{
                    AppLog.i(TAG, "onTokenRetrieved() - Token retrieval failed")

                }
            }

        })

         tokenUtils.getToken()

}
```

And here is the class making the call:

```
interface ApiClass {

@POST("url")
fun getToken(
    @Body body: TokenRequest
): Call<Token>
```

}

As I have it written, the callbacks for the IGetTokenListener are not firing. Where do I need to set them so that they fire when the API call in the TokenUtils object returns?

Comment: Well, nothing is going to happen unless you call `TokenUtils#getToken()` and since it's private and therefore can't be called from another class, and is apparently never called from inside `TokenUtils`, nothing can ever invoke the callback.

Comment: Apologies, I cut out the actual method call when I was deleting superfluous code. Edited back in

Comment: Put a breakpoint in onResponse() to verify if it's even hitting that success branch.

Comment: Is it even getting here? ```override fun onResponse(call: Call<Token>, response: Response<Token>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                callback?.onTokenRetrieved(true)

            }```

Comment: Well, there's still a lot you left out. What are `apiClass` and `Call`? And you are apparently calling a private method of `TokenUtils` from a different class - that isn't possible. If you want help debugging you will need to provide complete information. Best to include imports in the code snippets, and the source for any classes that are not standard library stuff.

Comment: Apologies, I did not make it clear that I am using Retrofit 2. I have added the class I used to store my api calls. I am hitting the code block for response.isSuccessful, it's just that the callback is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up turning the class into a Singleton and passing it context like this:

```
 companion object {

    private var instance: TokenUtils? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): TokenUtils {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(TokenUtils::class.java) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = TokenUtils(context)
            }
        }
        return instance!!
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this works and a lint warning over initialization of the instance variable tells me that passing context like this causes memory leaks, but it works.